# AMQ6004 : Multi Instance Queue Manager on Azure File Share Service

Tags: azure, ibm-mq, fileshare

**Components used:** IBM MQ 8.0.0.4 + Azure File share + Windows server 2016

**Scenario:**

I have created a multi instance queue manager using the azure file share drive mounted as the Z drive on the windows server 2016.

```
crtmqm -ld Z:\logs -md Z:\qmgrs QMHA1
```

has been run successfully and no errors have been reported.

But when I start the queue manager using the command below error is coming.

```
strmqm QMHA1
WebSphere MQ queue manager 'QMHA1' starting.
The queue manager is associated with installation 'Installation1'.
AMQ6004: An error occurred during WebSphere MQ initialization or ending.
```

Please help  me solve this issue to create a multi instance queue manager.

**Note:** When I created a queue manager and started on the local drive D:, queue manager was created and started successfully.

Comment: Do you see any files created in `%MQ_FILE_PATH%\errors` or in `Z:\qmgrs\QMHA1\errors`, if so look for entries in those files that correspond with the date and time you received the `AMQ6004` error.  You can also try to run a early trace with `strmqtrc -e -t detail -t all` before you run `strmqm` and then stop it with `endmqtrc -a` after.  The `*.TRC` file should be located in `%MQ_FILE_PATH%\trace`.  There should be at least three, one each for `strmqtrc`, `endmqtrc` and `strmqm`, you would be interested in the `strmqm` and any data it contains on why it is producing the error.

Comment: I have started the trace and started the queue manager. But still there are no error logs regarding the AMQ6004 present in any of the errors and trace files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the proper rights were not added to the file share folder, hence the above issue. Once the user permissions are added, the issue got resolved. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

When starting multi-instance queue managers, you have to use the `-x` flag, see [strmqm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083650_.htm) documentation:

```
strmqm -x QMHA1
```